# Managing a networked drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, logging, storage, file-permissions

We're having issues with people moving files both intentionally and accidentally on a networked drive. What would be a good way to establish accountability without bogging down the storage server? Is there a **lightweight** way to log file move actions? The only solution I am aware of is NTFS logging and that seems too resource intensive.

Comment: Seriously? You can't give us *any* more details? What kind of storage server is it?  Help us help you man.

Comment: @RyanRies updated with appropriate tags.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Log file moves? Prevent file moves? Still more info needed..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to be able to move files either intentionally or accidentally, then don't grant them the rights to do so.

If you do want them to have those rights, and be able to find out who did what and when, then you may have to look at NTFS auditing, but be aware that this can generate huge amounts of log data, especially if you're auditing successful operations (which you will need if you want to find out who moved or deleted something).

Comment: The users need the ability to create, delete and move files otherwise they wouldn't have the ability

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: Is there any alternative to ntfs logging? I'm aware of that solution already, I was hoping someone had a better idea.

Comment: Might have helped if you said that in your original question! Perhaps edit your question to help others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can "establish accountability" using native Windows tools and enabling object access auditing. This can be done either via GPO, or by local security policy. Once you've done that, incidents of users deleting files and moving files will be tracked in the server's Security log. You can scope the object access auditing to only certain areas/files on the file server.

Comment: How does this affect performance?

Comment: It has an impact but exactly how much of an impact depends entirely on your environment. Common sense applies in planning out your directory structure for simplicity (fewer ACL calculations, etc.) and scoping the access auditing appropriately.